# loop through same class elements and assign width and height

Tags: jquery, loops

I am a novice to js & jQuery and I need help to dynamically get the width and height of the img loaded and assign those dimensions to an absolute positioned element(.imgCover). All the images have different dimensions.

The js code below returns the dimensions of only the first image and doesn't count through to the last image. I am looking for a way to iterate through all the elements, get the photo dimensions - width and Height in each (.imageHolder) block and assign them to their respective (.imgCover) div.

Here is my current code.

Html

```
<div class="imageBlock">

<div class="imageHolder">
    <div class="imgCover"> </div>
    <img class="photo" src="images/img1.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="imageHolder">
    <div class="imgCover"> </div>
    <img class="photo" src="images/img2.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="imageHolder">
    <div class="imgCover"> </div>
    <img class="photo" src="images/img3.jpg"/>
</div>

 </div><!-- imageBlock-->
```

Javascript

```
var imageCover = $('.imgCover'),
    finalImage = $('.photo');

function resizeDiv() {
    imageCover.heightfinalImage.height());
imageCover.width(finalImage.width());
}

resizeDiv();

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeDiv();
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace resizeDiv() with this:

```
function resizeDiv() {

    $('.photo').each(function() {

        var height = $(this).height();
        var width = $(this).width();

        var $imgCover = $(this).prev(); // get the previous element to the photo (the image cover)

        $imgCover.height(height);
        $imgCover.width(width);
    });

}
```

You were almost there, what you were missing was the .each loop

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.